# Google tries to translate English HTML subscripts from Arabic

Tags: html, google-translate

I have a simple HTML page with some `<sub>` elements in it. For some reason, Google Translate offers to translate the subscripts from Arabic to English (despite being English to begin with), only moving them down a little when translated. The HTML page language is set to en-US. Is this just my computer being weird, or is there a code-related reason?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <!--<meta name="google" content="notranslate"> (this successfully gets rid of the translate popup, commented out for testing purposes)-->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.svg" type="image/svg"/>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body style="min-width: 0">
    <div id="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Added to #test by JS:

```
<div class="letter">A<sub>1</sub></div>
```

Website: https://test.edgeloop.repl.co
Screenshot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm1UM.png)

Comment: Please read the answers to the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552)

Comment: Added the html code and everything added by the JS file

Comment: `lang="en-US"` should be on the outer most `<html` other than that content language is [*detected*](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/2261cbe79fb40545cbeba8617c277685960ceb44/components/translate/core/language_detection/language_detection_util.cc#L149), so if you add a bunch more content it most likely wont happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that this is the correct code? You seem to have a `<html...>`-tag inside your `<head>`-tag. Remove the duplicate `html`-tag inside your `head`, and instead add the `lang="en"`-attribute to your outer-most `html`-tag.

Your code should thus look as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>test</title>
        ....
    </head>
    <body style="min-width: 0">
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If this does not immediately solve your problem, try clearing the google chrome cache as follows:

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the dev tools menu
2. Right-click your refreh-button
3. Select the option `empty cache and hard refresh`:
   [image]

---

If your webpage uses HTML and XML interchangably, you might need to add the following to your opening `<html>`-tag (see [this link](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)):

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    ...
</html>
```

---

If your Google Translate does **still** pop up, you have the following options:

1. add `translate="no"` to your root `html`-tag
2. add the class `notranslate` to your root `html`-tag
3. add `<meta name="google" content="notranslate">` to your `head`-tag

Your code should look as follows:

```
<html lang="en" translate="no" class="notranslate">
    <head>
        <meta name="google" content="notranslate"/>
        ....
    </head>
    ....
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't notice that, fixed now but the Google Translate problem is still there

Comment: Neither the hard refresh nor the XML part seemed to do anything, neither does restarting my computer or opening the page in an incognito window. It doesn't happen on Edge, but I don't think it has integrated Google Translate anyway.

Comment: And what about the last steps I described? i.e. adding the "notranslate" class, the "translate=no"-attribute and the corresponding meta-tag?

Comment: translate="no" and the class="notranslate" still didn't do anything, but the meta tag seemed to do the trick. It would still be nice to know why this is happening in the first place though. Were you able to replicate this problem?

Comment: @edgeloop: unfortunately, I am currently using edge, but I will try to reproduce this problem tomorrow on my chrome-machine. I do, however, not know, why this issue occurred for you :(

Answer (score 0):

@Lawrence Cherone's comment about adding more text seems to fix the problem, as does @unknown6656's suggestion of adding `<meta name="google" content="notranslate">`. I still don't know why subscripts are considered Arabic text, but adding English text seems to fix the problem. Thanks for all the answers.